# How to display image through download-only URL with View

Tags: image, react-native

My React Native 0.63.2 app will show images stored in cloud storage with code which is similar to below

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.stretch}
        source={{uri:'https://filefolder.download-only.com/image1.jpg'}}
      />
    </View>
```

The problem is that this `https://filefoler.download-only.com/image1.jpg` only allows to download file to local disk before opening it. One option I can think of is to download and save the image in a temp file locally and display it with `source={{uri:file:///path_to_image_file}}`. But this option would require explicit downloading of each image even before user clicks and opens it. Is it possible to make the download-only image behaving like a click-able image url? Ex, add `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"` before download-only url (something like source= {{uri:"data:image/png;base64,"+"https://filefolder.download-only.com/image1.jpg")

Comment: RN does support base64 although it is not clear what is the problem you are having. So the server does not give you access to the image itself? Is it a redirect? Can you return base64 encoding of the image?

Comment: Do I userstand? you wanna show a placeholder and then after pressing a button by user do the download image and show it? _OR_ your web source doesn't serve the image and just let you download it? your description is not clear.

Comment: @user938363 I don't understand what is the problem with you. Could you explain the details of your problem, please?

Comment: Most probably, your actual image url must be different from your so-called "download-only" url. Simply download a sample image and check its full image path in Downloads section in your preferred browser (for Chrome browser it is chrome://downloads/) and use this instead of https://filefolder.download-only.com/image1.jpg.

Comment: your example URL is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rn-fetch-blob` for this: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

- Fetch image as a blob
- Convert blob to base64 to display image, use following code to convert blob into base64

> ```
>  var reader = new FileReader();
>  reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
>  reader.onloadend = function() {
>      var base64data = reader.result;                
>      console.log(base64data);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

After ran some test code with a URL copied from the cloud storage, it turns out that the image can be displayed by `<Image>` as usual with the URL. There is no need to prefix the image path as we did for stream data.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Image
    style={styles.stretch}
    source={{uri:'https://filefolder.download-only.com/image1.jpg?expires=xxxxx&signature=xxxxxxxxxxxx'}}
  />
</View>
```

Please be noted that in browser the `url` (contains the authorization signature) only allows download the image to local file system. `<Image>` tag however will download the image first and display it in render view.